# WSO2 Identity Server - Error "Invalid Status" at entitlementServiceClient.getDecision

Tags: wso2, identity, xacml, wso2-identity-server

When using an access with userid & passsword based entitlement, and use of class "entitlementServiceClient", method "getDecision", the program always receives an error:  **"Invalid Status"**

Is there anything missing in the usage of this class:
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.ui.client.EntitlementServiceClient;

my statements are:

```
//initialize authentication admin stub
UnitTest1 remoteEntitlementClient = new UnitTest1();
//login using authentication admin stub providing valid credentials
remoteEntitlementClient.login(userid, password);
//initialize entitlement service stub with obtained authentication cookie
remoteEntitlementClient.initUnitTest1();
String decision = entitlementServiceClient.getDecision(myRequest);
System.out.println("\nXACML Decision is received : " + decision);
```

The authorization process seems to works fine and it receives a valid login confirmation and cookie (see log below).

```
oc2615188332 entitlement]$ sh ./testit.sh
Jul 17, 2015 8:10:37 PM     org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.StAXDialectDetector detectDialect
WARNING: Unable to determine dialect of the StAX implementation at    jar:file:/home/claudef/tmp/wso2/entitlement/lib/axiom_1.2.11.wso2v4.jar!/
The user admin logged in successfully.
The IdP authorization cookie is: JSESSIONID=CDEEA143EB95A5AABEB07F5A401633B4; Path=/; Secure=null; HttpOnly=null
XACML Decision is received : Invalid Status
Elapsed seconds decimal: 6.937248979
Elapsed seconds rounded: 6.937
Entitlement flow finished successfully
```

Thanks in advance for support and advice. 
Regards, 
Claude

Comment: Can you share your policy and request? Do you have a response?

Comment: The same Request and Policy (serverside) works well when using the class stub.EntitlementServiceStub in place of .ui.client.EntitlementServiceClient (the request and policy data is too long to copy into the forum). Is there an example available that illustrate the use of .ui.client.EntitlementServiceClient class with "cookie" passage in place of a initial user id based login? Thanks in advance for your support.